# Escape character not being recognized at the end of a string

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am writing code in Python to test a GUI component. I am comparing a string to a value that should be in an attributes box. The text I am searching for ends in a `*` character, and is being treated as a wild. This  is what I would expect, so naturally I added an `\` before the `*` to escape it. The variable `"value"` being passed in is `(text) 1 / \*`.

```
if node.exists and node.JavaFXObjectText == value:
    string = type + " for node and selection details match."
```

It does not enter the if statement because `node.JavaFXObjectText` is `(text) 1 / *` and value is `(text) 1 / \*`. I've also tried using the `re.escape()` function, and I get identical results. The issue only seems to happen when the character I'm trying to escape is the final character in the string, since I've used other regex with that same if statement. I've also tried it without the `\`, and the `*` still gets treated as a wild.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if node.exists and node.JavaFXObjectText == re.sub(r'\\\*$', '*', value):
```

to replace `\*` at the end of the string with a `*` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Ryszard Czech, I need to do some research as to what is going on in that sub function, but it didn't quite work. I got the same behavior as before.

`re.sub(r'\\*$', '*', value)`

Deleting one of the `\` as seen in the snippet above made it work, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: Your ``\*$`` regex  matches zero or more ``\`` characters at the end of string. So, you either remove all `*` at the end of string and append a single `*` or just append a `*` at the end of a string that does not end with `*`. This  does not sound like what you need.